# Cloudflare disable stripe webhook

Tags: laravel-5, stripe-payments, cloudflare

I am using the Laravel framework and Stripe for payment. When I get an answer from stripe webhook, I get a message like this:

> Just a moment... DDoS protection by Cloudflare

How to give access to Stripe?

Comment: Where are you seeing that message from exactly?

Comment: He is seeing it as part of the cloudflare protection. It is added by cloudlfare to prevent DDOS attacks and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the page you are referencing is the page CloudFlare shows to check and prevent against bots and floods before even loading website content.

As i see it you have 2 solutions:

**Option 1:**

In the firewall tab of your cloudflare dashboard you can whitelist all stripe webhook notification IPs found here: https://stripe.com/docs/ips

**Option 2:**
Go to page rules in cloudflare dashboard, make a new page rule where this is the rule:

If the URL matches: (https://example.com/webhookaddress)

And then add the setting that says "Disable security". In theory this should disable the cloudflare page.

https://example.com/webhookaddress is the URL of your webhook as configured in the stripe dashboard.