# Cloudflare with Stripe webhook returns HTTP 301 error

Tags: node.js, nginx, stripe-payments, cloudflare

I am running a NodeJS server on DigitalOcean that is listening for Stripe webhooks on the route `/stripe-webhook` with NGINX as a reverse proxy. It works perfectly during testing with the Stripe CLI on my local machine. However when I deploy to the server the Stripe dashboard always shows a HTTP 301 error code when it sends an event to the domain.

The domain is hosted on Cloudlfare which provides https. In the Stripe dashboard it is configured to send the webhook to `https://example.com/stripe-webhook` so I am not too sure why it is showing a redirect error? When I send a manual POST request to the same URL it works fine and does not return any redirect header.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54590611/cloudflare-disable-stripe-webhook If not, start point can be to check your nginx access log to see if request comes to nginx and not redirected by cloudfare

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my error: my Stripe dashboard was sending webhooks to:

`https://example.com/stripe-webook`

But my NGINX configuration was listening on :

`https://example.com/stripe-webhook/`

It was redirecting to add that extra slash on and since Stripe has a 0 redirects policy with webhooks it was throwing an error.